# Need help to make rig for rotating object to pull second object in a straight line?

Tags: rigging

Can anyone help me to make this simple rig?
I have tried so many IK but still no good
[image: Close up of the objects that move]

[image: screen shot of the entire setup.]

Comment: is it what you want to do? https://zupimages.net/up/21/51/n4yf.gif ... in that case you can use the Damped Track constraint

Comment: absolutely yes! so damped track is to choose, right? i will try this now

Comment: anyway, can you share the blend file of that sample please? hehe

Comment: ah, ignore my comment above. i already got it. thanks alot

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: @ApasipepOyong: please click on "accept answer" so other users although know that the answer helped you. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with the *Damped Track* constraint:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it, I decided to do this with a driver, instead of the much easier *Damped Track*:

[image: Example created using driver]

The Z *rotation* of the first bone is used to drive the Z *location* of the second bone.  Here's the driver for the second bone:

[image: driver for the Z location of the second bone.]

There's no reason to prefer the Damped Track or the driver over the other in general, but sometimes other constraints will prevent you from selecting one, so it's good to know the other is available.